# How to install python packages for use in a jupyter notebook kernel?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I installed Python 3 kernel using the following commands

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5 ipykernel
source activate py35
python -m ipykernel install –user –name py35 –display-name “Python 3”
```

When I import numpy in a python 3 notebook, I get `ImportError: No module named numpy`. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `conda install -n py35 numpy`

Answer (score 0):

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5 ipykernel
source activate py35
pip install numpy
```